# Is equal sign ('=') passing a copy or a reference in case of a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got this code snippet, which converts a flat list to a dictionary:
(for example, from:

```
`X = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['A', 'B', 'D'],['W','X'],['W','Y','Z']]`
```

to

```
{'A': {'B': {'C': {}, 'D': {}}}, 'W': {'X': {}, 'Y': {'Z': {}}}}
```

the code:

```
d = {}

for path in X:
    current_level = d
    for part in path:
        if part not in current_level:
            current_level[part] = {}
        current_level = current_level[part]
        print('current_level = ', current_level)
        print('d = ', d)
print(d)
```

and here's the output:

```
current_level =  {}
d =  {'A': {}}
current_level =  {}
d =  {'A': {'B': {}}}
current_level =  {}
d =  {'A': {'B': {'C': {}}}}
current_level =  {'B': {'C': {}}}
d =  {'A': {'B': {'C': {}}}}
current_level =  {'C': {}}
d =  {'A': {'B': {'C': {}}}}
current_level =  {}
d =  {'A': {'B': {'C': {}, 'D': {}}}}
current_level =  {}
d =  {'A': {'B': {'C': {}, 'D': {}}}, 'W': {}}
current_level =  {}
d =  {'A': {'B': {'C': {}, 'D': {}}}, 'W': {'X': {}}}
current_level =  {'X': {}}
d =  {'A': {'B': {'C': {}, 'D': {}}}, 'W': {'X': {}}}
current_level =  {}
d =  {'A': {'B': {'C': {}, 'D': {}}}, 'W': {'X': {}, 'Y': {}}}
current_level =  {}
d =  {'A': {'B': {'C': {}, 'D': {}}}, 'W': {'X': {}, 'Y': {'Z': {}}}}
```

So with `current_level = d`, it seems we are passing a reference to the dictionary `d`. Indeed, this dictionary doesn't appear anymore in the code after that.

But when we do: `current_level = current_level[part]`: the `current_level` dict is given the value an empty dict `{}` whereas `d` doesn't change (see the output).

So I'm confused: is it a reference to the dict or a distinct copy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always by reference but not the same reference as you would have in C++.
`current_level = d` means that `current_level` is now pointing to `d` and not that it is a reference to `d`.

This means that when you do `current_level = current_level[part]`, you do not update `d` with `current_level[part]` but update the value of the object pointed by `current_level` to be `current_level[part]`